# Set textfile content as a array

Tags: java, arrays

Hi, I am totally new in java. 
This is my java code:

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.BufferedReader;

public class readw {
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\run\\input.txt"));
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            lines.add(line);
        }
    } finally {
        reader.close();
    }
    String[] array = lines.toArray();
}
}
```

When I am trying to compile it I got this type of error:

```
line 8: can not find symbol List (L)and ArrayList(A)
```

I am trying to get content of my text file and want to set in to as a array.

Comment: What does not work? What error do you get?

Comment: I might suggest changing `String[] array = lines.toArray();` to `String[] array = lines.toArray(new String[lines.size()]);` but otherwise it looks fine...

Comment: where the problem lies?

Comment: @LutzHorn line 8: can not find symbol List (L)and ArrayList(A)

Comment: Open javadoc, it has good explanation. Also look at the next method: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray%28%29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
```

---

> yes its work now i want to see the array result. how?

With

```
System.out.println(lines);
```

Comment: Add it right after "String[] array = lines.toArray();" where lines is still visible.

Comment: ohh yes i try this but i think problem is i have a textfile content something like this type: `2010,2011,2012` with comma

Comment: Commas in String object is just a string nothing special. System.out.println() will surely work on such ArrayList<String>. Update question (add below to what you already posted) with the code that does not work with short description please.

Answer (score 1):

You need to import all the classes you use.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
```